# redirect back to previously protected page based on last locale

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have a problem with logic that require redirect to previous protected page after login.

I'm using my own login page, using **Google** Credential, and set multilingual website usimg Next/router locale.

Here's my **NextAuth** config:

```
export default NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        // OAuth authentication providers
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            // Allows relative callback URLs
            if (url.startsWith("/")) return `${baseUrl}${url}`
            // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
            else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
            return baseUrl
        }
}
})
```

And this is my **signIn** onClick code:

```
onClick={() => signIn("google", { callbackUrl: locale == "id-ID" ? '/app' : "/en-US/app" })}
```

I open for clearer explanation and easy to understand, Tq

Answer (score 2):

The [callbackUrl](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) is the location where you want to send the user after they authentication:

> The callbackUrl specifies to which URL the user will be redirected after signing in. Defaults to the page URL the sign-in is initiated from.

Currently, you are manually redirecting them to either `'/app' : "/en-US/app"`.

If you want to return the user the page they were previously trying to access, you can do something like:

```
function handleSignIn() {
  const router = useRouter();
  signIn("google", { callbackUrl: router.asPath });
}
```

```js
onClick={handleSignIn}
```

The `redirect` callback is not needed in this case, as the logic you have there is already the default logic.

Comment: but when I navigate to en-US before login, example `/en-US/app/categories`, and login, it come back to login page

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. What does `router.asPath` evaluate to in the function `handleSignIn` example before `signIn` is called?

Comment: it should be redirect back to protected url that user has been visited

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should create an auth context. The AuthProvider will be your root component and there you'll validate if user is authenticated or not and redirect to login page if needed

```
type ContextType = ....

const AuthContext = createContext( {} as ContextType )

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!authenticated) {
      router.replace( `/login?callbackUrl=${ 
        router.asPath
          .replace( '/', '' )
          .replace( /&/g, '_' ) 
        }` )
      return
    }

    if(authenticated) {
      // go to default page
      if(!router.query.callbackUrl){
        router.replace('/dashboard')
        return
      }

      // redirects to your callback url
     router.replace( `/${ router.query.callbackUrl.replace( /_/g, '&' ) }` )
    }
  }, [authenticated])

  useEffect(() => {
    setAuthenticated(() => !!user)
  }, [user])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={ useMemo(() => ({
        // add here all your ContextType values
        // eg: user, setUser, authenticated
      }), [
        // add here all values those changes, eg: user, authenticated
      ])}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export function useAuth(): ContextType {
  const context = useContext( AuthContext )
  if ( !context ) throw new Error( 'Auth context is invalid' )
  return context
}
```

and use it in your _app:

```
....
<AuthProvider>
  <Component { ...pageProps } />
</AuthProvider >
```

now inside your `login` page use the context:

```
....
// I'm using setUser supposing you exported it inside useMemo
const {setUser} = useAuth()


... handle your login login

setUser(() => userData)
```

Now every time your `authenticated` variable changes it will redirect to desired pages

this a very simple example but I'm using this in all my projects and works perfectly